# mapnik-renderd error: FATAL: role "_renderd" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, mapnik, apache

mapnik-renderd error: FATAL: role "_renderd" does not exist

I've been following [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-20-04-osm#comments) tutorial to making an osm tile server on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL), but after restarting the renderd service with `sudo service renderd restart` (9th step) and navigating to *localhost/osm/0/0/0.png* from a browser I get a 404 error. Then when I check syslog, I find this:

> renderd: ERROR: An error occurred while loading the map layer
> 'default': Postgis Plugin: connection to server on socket
> "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "_renderd"
> does not exist#012Connection string: ' dbname=gis
> connect_timeout=4'#012  encountered during parsing of layer
> 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 803 of
> '/home/osm/openstreetmap-carto/style.xml'

I'm using a map I exported from [openstreetmap.org](https://openstreetmap.org) via Overpass API

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by renaming the user osm to _renderd in postgresql and replacing it in other files with the same name as well.